# Sum of a nested iif statement

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have the following nested iif statement that brings back an error  "End of Statement expected."
Can someone please help?  I know its probably very straightforward but i have been looking at this for sometime.
Thanks

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "A*", 6, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "A", 5, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "B", 4, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "C" , 3, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "D" , 2 , IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "E", 1, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "E/U", 0))))))) - IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "A*" , 6, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "A", 5, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "B", 4 , IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "C", 3, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "D", 2, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "E" , 1, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "U", 0)))))))))

Comment: I think you have 15x **(** but 16x **)**

Answer (score 0):

I needed an else 0 statement, added this to the code to give the below and all is good

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "A*", 6, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "A", 5, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "B", 4, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "C" , 3, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "D" , 2 , IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "E", 1, IIF(Fields!Grade.Value = "E/U", 0, 0))))))) - IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "A*" , 6, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "A", 5, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "B", 4 , IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "C", 3, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "D", 2, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "E" , 1, IIF(Fields!Target_Grade.Value = "U", 0, 0))))))))

Comment: And remove a bracket like the other answer :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have one too many closing brackets- you could try removing the last bracket.

(I pasted your code into Notepad++ and put in a carriage return for each opening bracket and closing bracket. Notepad++ highlights the matching opening and closing brackets, and there was one left over))

Comment: Thanks that has removed that error, but I now have, "Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'." instead!

Comment: You needed an else 0 statement: if you add it to the code all will be good